# How to add new training phrases to Rasa NLU dynamically?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I have trained a Rasa bot. I want to add new training phrases to an intent via code and trigger intent so that this new training phrases is available for next utterance. How do I do that?

Could not find any relevant reference in the Rasa documentation. In case of Rasa interactive learning, it seams it is a manual process where a human has to sit an train the model.

Comment: Please check this https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/pages/http-api#operation/trainModel

Answer (score 3):

You cannot train your Rasa model dynamically. If you add new training examples to your NLU data, you need to retrain the model to have the model understand the new intents.
If you do interactive learning, you will generate new training data. That data can be used to re-train your model afterwards.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "dynamically". Training is mandatory to take new data into consideration. It may take maybe 1 or 2 minutes on a powerful server. During this time the new data is still not available. Once done, you can restart resa on the server and ok you start using the new model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use an Interactive session with bot. By doing this you can train bot with some new utterance and new answers